# call .bat is not recognized in task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have this batch file. That calls another batch file:

```
echo cd /d %~dp0
cd %~dp0
call AddAlltoVss-SVN.bat
pause
```

If I run it manually it works ,but it doesnt work if I run it through task Scheduler:

```
Error : 'AddAlltoVss-SVN.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

It was working normally before I am not sure what happen

[image]

Comment: add `cd /d %~dp0` at the start of the script. scheduler does not start the script in its home dir.

Comment: or add the %~dp0 directly to the call.

Comment: @Moudiz - the `/D` switch is missing.Script is on `D:` and the system drive  is `C:`

Comment: @npocmaka I have added /d. Still same error . Ill add a new screenshot

Comment: @Moudiz - but only the `echo` line has the `/d` switch.The line where `cd` command is called there's no such switch.

Comment: In the line `C:\WINDOWS\system32>call AddAlltoVss-SVN.bat` you should recognize that the directory is wrong

Comment: @npocmaka yes i noticed that and i fixed . it work thanks please add it as answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the start of the script. Scheduler does not start the script in its home directory but in the system32. the `/d` switch is needed in case the script directory is not system drive.